# Connecting Flash to Ports using socket programming

Tags: flash, port, socketserver

I need to send a signal output from flash application to an external hardware device. I know the concept, that a socket server is required in between to connect the both. Flash will communicate to the port using socket server and the external device will receive that signal from the port. But I am not comfortable with socket programming to communicate between flash and the ports.

Answer (score 0):

A few years ago I got serial communication in as3 using the Socket class and serproxy.
For some reason, back then the serproxy shipping with [as3glue](https://code.google.com/p/as3glue/) worked for me.

You can see my resources from those experiments [here](http://www.lfpug.com/arduino-actionscript/)

I haven't used as3 with serial recently so my approach might be outdated.
Perhaps this [as3-arduino-connector](https://code.google.com/p/as3-arduino-connector/) project might be more relevant.

Comment: thans a alot,,I will try this,,but actually I am a beginner so finding it little complex,, Lets c..! :)

Comment: hey,,can you tell me that where to place the serproxy files and any procedure to check whether the program is working or not without any arduino hardware, Its urgent,,,thanks in advance

Comment: Download the as3glue package, read the readme and when you have the arduino hardware change the serproxy cfg to match the com port/baud rate of yours. If you want to test serial port communication, you will need a serial device. Otherwise, you can just have some dummy data, but this will only help simulate what will happen when you get the data, but not the actual serial communication part of course.